# Правильная работа с ООП в PHP

Tags: php, ооп

Просьба помочь мне разобраться с ООП в PHP. Ранее как то мне такой опыт не требовался и ООП старался как-то обойти стороной, но времена меняются как говорится и нужно познавать что то новое.
И перед вопросом своим скажу что я знаю и вроде как понимаю и если в чем то ошибусь то если не сложно поправьте пожалуйста.
И так ООП у нас записывается в классах

```
class Test{

}
$test = new Test()
```

Так же у нас есть методы которые начинаются с function.

Вот представим у меня есть два файла test1.php и test2.php. В test1.php создаем класс для подключения к бд и несколько методов с запросами.

test1.php

```
class Pdo{
  protected $pdo = null;
  protected $stmt1 = null;
  protected $stmt2 = null;
  function __construct () {
    try {
      $this->pdo = new PDO(
        "mysql:host=".DB_HOST.";charset=".DB_CHAR.";dbname=".DB_NAME,
        DB_USER, DB_PASS
      );
    } catch (Exception $ex) { exit($ex->getMessage()); }
  }
  function __destruct () {
    if ($this->pdo !== null) { $this->pdo = null; }
    if ($this->stmt1 !== null) { $this->stmt1 = null; }
    if ($this->stmt2 !== null) { $this->stmt2 = null; }
  }

  function query1 () {
    $this->stmt1 = $this->pdo->prepare(
      "SELECT *, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`time`) AS `unix`
       FROM `score` ORDER BY `time` DESC LIMIT 1"
    );
    $this->stmt1->execute();
    return $this->stmt1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  }

  function query2 () {
    $this->stmt2 = $this->pdo->prepare(
      "SELECT *, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`time`) AS `unix`
       FROM `score` ORDER BY `time` DESC LIMIT 1"
    );
    $this->stmt2->execute();
    return $this->stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  }

}
```

Скажу сразу что бы не было вопросов в методах query1 и query2 один и тот же запрос для примера и не более того. И вот как мне правильно подключить class из test1.php в class test2.php

test2.php

```
class Test{
  function test1() {

    // Тут выводим какой то html код в котором нужно выполнить
    // в первой половине кода query1 ну а во второй query2
    //
    // Простой пример
    echo "<div>". query1 ."</div>";
    echo "<div>". query2 ."</div>";
    //
    // И тут же сразу спрошу что бы вызвать из этого метода метод test2
    // Так должно выглядить?

    $this->test2();

  }
  function test2() {
    ***
  }
}
```

Если можно на вопросы не много развернуто ответить заранее Вам благодарен. Вижу что не очень сложно. Вот только вроде бы на первый взгляд простые моменты не как не поддаются пониманию.

Comment: вам стоит почитать хоть какую-нибудь статейку про ООП в php. Вопросы ваши совершенно элементарны и говорят о том, что вы предметом совсем не владеете

Comment: жестокий вопрос. Если сейчас начать разбирать даже ваш пример, получится огромное количество пробелов, "а почему так?". ООП это все же методология и подход и тут вот так просто не расскажешь в двух словах. Даже глядя на пример прежде всего возникает несколько моментов: во-первых класс отвечающий за соединение и выполнение запросов к БД не должен содержать конкретных запросов. Это один уровень абстракции. Те или иные запросы, основанные на каких-то знаниях о структуре таблиц - это Модель, и это другой уровень абстракции. И.т.п. Постарайтесь почитать теорию.

Comment: Читал вот только не до конца появилось понимание.
Вот что то подобное я нормально своил

class Test1{
    protected $var = "Тут что то выводится.";
    function method1(){
      $this->method2();
    }
    function method2(){
      echo $this->var;
    }
    
}

$qqq = new Test1();

$qqq->method1();

Comment: Дмитрий ну во первых очень много вопросов я думаю не будет Просто надо уяснить какие то моменты.
Второе через __construct я делаю подключение к БД и ниже два метода запросов которые буду использоваться везде так или иначе и что бы их не дублировать думал написать в одном месте и всего один раз. Или это не правильно?
И третье теорию читал вот и остались некоторые вопросы которые не очень получилось осознать.

Comment: Сперва разъясни что значит твое "И вот как мне правильно подключить class из test1.php в class test2.php"? Как ты собираешься вставить один класс в другой? Класс можно либо использовать либо расширить с помощью `extends`. Опиши более конкретно что тебе нужно?

Comment: Если ты имеешь ввиду подключить реализацию класса из файла test1.php в файл test2.php то есть директивы `include`, `require`, `include_once` и `require_once`, также можно использовать автозагрузку классов - но для этого именна классов должны соответствовать именам файлов и не являться зарезервированными словами. В общем жду подробностей

Comment: Reiji Akkerman ниже я написал код но не могу точно быть уверен что он правильный. Что касается автозагрузки это конечно хорошо и обязательно обращу на него внимание мне бы понять правильно ли усвоил в целом всё или нет.

Answer (score -1):

Сейчас вроде бы не много разобрался хотел бы что бы сказали правильно ли делаю или нет. Так же два файла test1.php и test2.php

test1.php я переписывать не буду так как оно осталось неизменным **⇧**

test2.php

```
<?php

include 'test1.php';

class Test{
  protected $var;
  function __construct(Pdo $var2){
    $this->var = $var2;
  }
  function __destruct(){
    if($this->var !== null){ $this->var = null; }
  }

  function method1(){
    echo "<div>" . $this->var->query1() . "</div>";
    echo "<div>" . $this->var->query2() . "</div>";
  }

}

$res = new Test(new Pdo);
$res->method1();

?>
```